# Not able to insert a datetime value in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I was creating a database and I wanted a column to accept the current date if no date value is inserted. Code worked, but inserting the date didn't.

I used the `check` constraint and the `default` along while creating the table

```
OrderDate datetime null check (OrderDate <= getdate()) default getdate()
```

This is the code used to create the table:

```
create table Transactions.OrderDetails 
(
    PurchaseOrderID int identity(1, 1) primary key
  , EmployeeID int not null
  , ItemID int not null
  , OrderDate datetime null check (OrderDate <= getdate()) default getdate()
  , ReceivingDate datetime null --check (ReceivingDate > OrderDate)
  , QO int not null --check (QO > QR)
  , QR int null check (QR > 0)
  , UnitPrice money not null check (UnitPrice > 0)
  , ShippingMethod char(6) not null
  , OrderStatus varchar(50) not null
 )
```

Comment: Well, that's a shame but unless you show us how you declared your table, and how you tried to insert a row into it, that's pretty much all we can say.

Comment: I used the CHECK constraint and the DEFAULT along while creating the table    HERE is the OrderDate datetime NULL CHECK(OrderDate<=getdate()) DEFAULT getdate(),

Comment: Show us, don't tell us, please show the syntax you used, both for creating your table and inserting into the table.

Comment: This is the code used while creating the table  "create table Transactions.OrderDetails
(
 PurchaseOrderID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,   
    EmployeeID int NOT NULL,
 ItemID int NOT NULL,   
    OrderDate datetime NULL CHECK(OrderDate<=getdate()) DEFAULT getdate(),
 ReceivingDate datetime NULL CHECK(ReceivingDate>OrderDate),
 QO int NOT NULL CHECK(QO>QR),
 QR int NULL CHECK(QR>0),
 UnitPrice money NOT NULL CHECK(UnitPrice>0),     
    ShippingMethod char(6) NOT NULL,  
 OrderStatus varchar(50) NOT NULL,
)"

Comment: Please edit it into your question instead of posting it as a comment. Indent the sql with 4 spaces as well to get code highlighting.

Comment: Worked Perfectly. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the column `not null`, and add a default constraint of `getdate()` or `getutcdate()` for a `datetime` datatype.

```
create table Orders (
    id int
  , OrderDate_notnull datetime not null default getdate()
  , OrderDate_null datetime null default getdate()
);

/* nullable column with default not specified in insert uses default*/
insert into Orders (id) values (1);

/* nullable column with default specified in insert remains null */
insert into Orders (id,OrderDate_null) values (2,null);

/* non-nullable column specified with null value throws an error */
--insert into Orders (id,OrderDate_notnull) values (3,null);

select * from Orders;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/CCNT4591

returns:

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id |  OrderDate_notnull  |   OrderDate_null    |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2017-07-08 18:10:50 | 2017-07-08 18:10:50 |
|  2 | 2017-07-08 18:10:50 | NULL                |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: @OsagieEhimare .. Be nice and mark the question as answer to indicate that the answer solved your problem.

Comment: Forgot that am new here, not used to all of this tho.